# The processing of image captchas using computer vision

Tags: graphics

I want to locate the **coordinates** of the object in the 'small image' within the 'large image'. If you have any ideas, please let me know.

I have tried `feature matching`, but the success rate is low.

---

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: The whole point of CAPTCHA is to prevent you from doing this. If common CV applications could do it there wouldn't be any point.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that for your case you could simply rotate the small picture for N times and apply template matching for each of the rotated small pictures.

Also applied median filters to the image to reduce the noise

Example:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_small = cv.imread('small.png', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_big = cv.imread('big.png', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)

img_small = cv.cvtColor(img_small, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_big = cv.cvtColor(img_big, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

img_big = cv.medianBlur(img_big, 3)

rows,cols = img_small.shape[:2]

img_small_rotated = list()

n = 20

for i in range(0,n):
    M = cv.getRotationMatrix2D(((cols-1)/2.0,(rows-1)/2.0),360*(i/n),1)
    img_small_rot = cv.warpAffine(img_small,M,img_small.shape[:2],borderValue = (255,255,255))
    img_small_rot = cv.medianBlur(img_small_rot, 3)
    img_small_rotated.append(img_small_rot)

im_show_all_templates = np.concatenate(img_small_rotated, axis=1)

plt.imshow(im_show_all_templates)
plt.show()

max_loc_global = None
max_val_global = 0

for i in img_small_rotated:
    res = cv.matchTemplate(img_big,i,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(res)
    if max_val > max_val_global:
        max_val_global = max_val
        max_loc_global = max_loc

print(max_val_global, max_loc_global)

top_left = max_loc_global
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + cols, top_left[1] + rows)

cv.rectangle(img_big,top_left, bottom_right, 0, 2)

plt.imshow(img_big)
plt.show()
```

result:

[image]

You can use similar techniques to expand the template matching space in other ways (scaling, filtering, rotating), but for your application rotation appears to be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. While the suggested method can be applied to some cases of this captcha type, it might not be feasible for others due to distorted images or objects being partially obscured. I will provide additional examples in the article for your review. Thank you very much.

Comment: Apologies for bothering you, but I'm really not proficient in this matter. Does this method still have a margin of error, right? I just uploaded a new example, and this method produced an incorrect result.

Comment: You are correct, the method is not perfect, but you can try to expand on the idea introducing new variations upon the template to try and make it more robust, or change the preprocessing on the big image(different filtering, etc.). Maybe an algorithm based on convolution neural networks that extract features and matches with the template would yield better results, however the complexity would be much higher.

Answer (score 1):

If the layout is always the same, you could try to simply compare color histograms of each of the 6 icons to the one you are looking for. So you crop out the icons and compute histograms for each one. Then you compute the distances between the `SMALL IMAGE` and the cropped icon histograms and take the minimum.

The problem with this approach is that you need to be able to determine the layout of the icons, but if you're able to do that, this solution should work, given that there's not too much occlusion or color variance.
The advantage is that histograms are rotation invariant so there's less processing than using template matching. Also consider normalizing the histograms and preprocessing the images before comparing.

Comment: I see no promise in color histograms. those captchas are designed to not be that easily breakable. the icons are either all colorful or all kinda dull, in each of the given examples.

Comment: Still, the response will most likely be strongest on the matching icon, especially if you preprocess the images to either improve the captcha icon or add noise to the `small image` icon. If you then combine the score with template matching score you'd probably get good enough results with a fairly simple approach.